# orbit-db examples errors : 429 (too many requests) in ipfs.js:311138

Tags: ipfs, orbitdb

When I run the [orbit-db](https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db) example It works, but there are errors in console.

> ipfs.js:311138 GET
>   https://node0.preload.ipfs.io/api/v0/refs?r=true&arg=Qmb3vcXiX6dBHjWojh817SoVUdBmxiycrPs23ySeMRHT5v
>   **429 (Too Many Requests)**

This message is repeated with different hash.

Error Messages:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating IPFS use:

```js
this.ipfs = new Ipfs({
  preload: { enabled: false },
  ....
}
```

https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db/issues/560#issuecomment-461361478